# i want to stop ajax request after 10 request in async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have async function sends ajax request based on the last ajax response the function works fine but it sends many requests i need to make interval 5 seconds between each request and i want to stop ajax calls after 20 request.

this is the The JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

$(document).on('input', '#repSlider2', function() {
    $('#repoutput2').html( $(this).val() );
});

async function scrapePage(url, data = {}) {
  const response = await $.ajax({
    url,
    data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
  });
    var output2 = "";
    var FbUsersId = $('#FbUsersId').val();
  console.log(response);
             $.each(response, function(key, value) { 
               output2 += value.group_id+'\r\n';
                });  
            $("#FbUsersId").val(FbUsersId+output2);
            var text = $('#FbUsersId').val();
            text = text.replace(/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/gm, "");
            // $(FbUsersId).val(text);


  // If there is no next page, show the error.
  const nextPage = 'exGoupsReq.php?next='+response[0].next_page;
  if (typeof nextPage === 'undefined') {
    $(".successMSG").html(
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "danger",
        title: "No more pages",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 2000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
      }).then(function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
        } else {
          //if no clicked => do something else
        }
      })
    );

    return;
  }

  // Otherwise scrape the next page.
  await scrapePage(nextPage, data);
}

$("#getUsersId").on("submit", async function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var keyword = $("#Keyword").val();
  var fbAcc = $("#fbAccs").val();

  const data = { 
    Keyword: keyword, 
    fb_acc: fbAcc 
  };

  $(".submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  await scrapePage("exGoupsReq.php", data);

});



});
```

I tried a lot, but all failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set a `delay` function with `promise` and `setTimeout`

```
async function delay(ms = 300) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```

which should delay the execution of the next `scrapePage` function by 5 seconds.

```
await delay(5000)
await scrapePage(nextPage, data);
```

And set a `counter` and on each request increment it with one, and when it reaches `20`, just return the function and stop the recursion.

This the full example of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(document).on("input", "#repSlider2", function () {
        $("#repoutput2").html($(this).val());
    });

    async function delay(ms = 300) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    }
    let count = 0;

    async function scrapePage(url, data = {}) {
        count++;
        if (count >= 20) {
            return;
        }
        const response = await $.ajax({
            url,
            data,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
        });
        var output2 = "";
        var FbUsersId = $("#FbUsersId").val();
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
            output2 += value.group_id + "\r\n";
        });
        $("#FbUsersId").val(FbUsersId + output2);
        var text = $("#FbUsersId").val();
        text = text.replace(/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/gm, "");
        // $(FbUsersId).val(text);

        // If there is no next page, show the error.
        const nextPage = "exGoupsReq.php?next=" + response[0].next_page;
        if (typeof nextPage === "undefined") {
            $(".successMSG").html(
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: "danger",
                    title: "No more pages",
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 2000,
                    timerProgressBar: true,
                }).then(function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                    } else {
                        //if no clicked => do something else
                    }
                })
            );

            return;
        }
        await delay(5000)
        // Otherwise scrape the next page.
        await scrapePage(nextPage, data);
    }

    $("#getUsersId").on("submit", async function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var keyword = $("#Keyword").val();
        var fbAcc = $("#fbAccs").val();

        const data = {
            Keyword: keyword,
            fb_acc: fbAcc,
        };

        $(".submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        await scrapePage("exGoupsReq.php", data);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks it works fine <3 , i'm from egypt too